# Stored Procedure only inserting into one table using a declared table and not inserting with the remaining declared tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I had posted this stored procedure earlier because of a different issue that was resolved. But I have noticed that when I execute the stored procedure, and give it the values that it will be receiving from other code, it is only inserting on the Quiz table and not the other 2 tables, Games and Video.

Here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Add$Subject$Info
(
@SubjectName varchar(50),
@SubjectDescription varchar(max),
@QuizIDString varchar(100),
@GamesIDString varchar(100),
@VideoIDString varchar(100)
)
as

--declare variables
declare @theSubID int
declare @quizIDLength int
declare @gamesIDLength int
declare @videoIDLength int
declare @quizIDs varchar(200)
declare @gamesIDs varchar(200)
declare @videoIDs varchar(200)
declare @numberCount int
declare @sTemp varchar(100)

--initializing variables
set @quizIDLength = LEN(@QuizIDString)
set @gamesIDLength = LEN(@GamesIDString)
set @videoIDLength = LEN(@VideoIDString)
set @quizIDs = ''
set @gamesIDs = ''
set @videoIDs = ''
set @numberCount = 1


--declare temp tables
declare @Q table --Quiz 
(
QuizID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

declare @G table --Games
(
GamesID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

declare @V table --Videos
(
VideoID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

insert into[Subjects]
(SubjectName, SubjectDescription)
values
(@SubjectName, @SubjectDescription)
set @TheSubID = @@IDENTITY

--Check to see what strings are full then entering ids if true
--Quizzes first
if(@QuizIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@quizIDLength)
    begin
    set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@QuizIDString, @numberCount, 1)
    if(@sTemp = ',')
    begin 
        insert into @Q (QuizID, SubjectID) values (@quizIDs, @theSubID)
        set @quizIDs = ''
    end
    if(@sTemp <> ',')
    begin
        set @quizIDs = @quizIDs + @sTemp
    end
    set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
    end
end
--Games second
if(@gamesIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@gamesIDLength)
    begin
        set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@GamesIDString, @numberCount, 1)
        if(@sTemp = ',')
        begin 
            insert into @G (GamesID, SubjectID) values (@gamesIDs, @theSubID)
            set @gamesIDs = ''
        end
        if(@sTemp <> ',')
        begin
            set @gamesIDs = @gamesIDs + @sTemp
        end
        set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
    end
end
    --Videos third
    if(@videoIDLength > 0)
    begin
        while(@numberCount <=@videoIDLength)
        begin
            set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@VideoIDString, @numberCount, 1)
            if(@sTemp = ',')
            begin 
                insert into @V (VideoID, SubjectID) values (@videoIDs, @theSubID)
                set @videoIDs = ''
            end
            if(@sTemp <> ',')
            begin
                set @videoIDs = @videoIDs + @sTemp
            end
            set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
        end
        end
    --inserting the ids to subjectinfo table
    insert into [SubjectInfo]
        (SubjectID, QuizID)
    select SubjectID, QuizID
    from @Q

    --Games
    insert into [SubjectInfo]
        (SubjectID, GameID)
    select SubjectID, GamesID
    from @G

    --Video
    insert into [SubjectInfo]
        (SubjectID, VideoID)
    select SubjectID, VideoID
    from @V
```

I have tried putting the insert in on its respective if statement, and I even tried using an inner join to do the insert at one shot, but it didn't really work out to well.

So why would the data only insert on the first insert, using my declared tables, and not on the others?
I could fix this by coding it with C#/ASP.NET, but then I would have to open a connection multiple times and I don't really want to do that because I'm already writing the stored procedure to insert what I need so I may as well deal with it in the stored procedure while I'm writing it.

Any ideas or can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to reset `@numberCount` to 0.

Comment: Also use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` function, it can return wrong results if this proc is being called simultaneously.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Hi, thanks for your help earlier. You are right I had to reset my counter after each use. Now that I am looking at the inserted code, I'm realizing that I should do one complete INSERT and not INSERT separately. Its causing me to have more rows that are nulls, and not having it be one row with a null or not. Any ideas? I had tried using an inner join on the declared tables and do one complete insert but as mentioned, it didn't work out right.

Comment: @M.Ali, I have read about the two before and have always used @@IDENTITY and never ran into any issues, that doesn't mean that it probably won't happen at some point, So I should consider starting to use SCOPE_IDENTITY :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Sorry about that, the more I look at it the data the more I think I should leave it that way, with the multiple inserts.

Comment: You should definitely use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.  To clarify the issue, @@IDENTITY is a single global variable, visible to all connections.  If you only ever have one connection to the database, @@IDENTITY will work, but as soon as you have more than one concurrent connection you risk having connection A get the last identity value generated via connection B. However; the value returned by SCOPE_IDENTITY() is scoped privately to the connection, so each connection sees its own last identity value. You **absolutely** should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), not @@IDENTITY.

Comment: Actually, it goes a little further than that... If you have sproc A and sproc B, and both perform inserts into tables with IDENTITY columns, @@IDENTITY still gives you the last IDENTITY value generated even if you only use one connection.  So sproc A could do an identity insert, call sproc B, which does an identity insert, then back in sproc A you access @@IDENTITY, but what you get is the identity value created during the call to sproc B, not the identity value generated in sproc A before the call to B. If that sounds confusing at all... all the more reason to just use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: One of the classic cases here is that if you have a sproc that inserts into a table with an identity column, and that table has a trigger, and the trigger does an insert into a different table with an identity column, then you get the identity value generated by the **trigger**, which can definitely cause hair loss. Where might you find this? Triggers can be used for logging and all kinds of other totally legitimate purposes. You want to avoid unintended side-effects. Actually, you want to avoid *any* side effects.  @@IDENTITY is super vulnerable to magical side effects.

Comment: @Craig, very informative, I appreciate that very much. I understand what you are explaining about the two. I should start using SCOPE_IDENTITY, but I have never ran into any issues using @@IDENTITY, so its bound to catch up with me at some point in time and chances are at that time it will be something major. So I better start using it now. I'm glad you took the time to explain.

Comment: @Craig - `@@IDENTITY` is not a global variable. It never returns a value generated by another session. The difference is purely as to whether or not you see values generated up and down the call stack in the *same* session.

Comment: For such problem it is you who can debug.Because we don't know requirement and wht parameter to pass .In such situation,i always comment part of my code and execute only part of code using print variable and verify data.Like you can comment "--Games second " onwards.
Also print @TheSubID and other variable involve so far.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks, you're right, @@IDENTITY is scoped to the connection. In retrospect, I knew that. I should have double-checked my statements rather than going straight from memory. But the same caveats really still apply; call another stored proc that inserts into a 2nd table with an identity column, or have a trigger do the same (the trigger might appear later!), and you'll get the wrong identity value.  SCOPE_IDENTITY() is a better bet. Even then, call it from within the scope you care about. Also, be wary of IDENT_CURRENT('tablename'); it gets the last ident value from ANY connection.